# "Always" location permission... only used occasionally but always showing arrow?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, location-services, background-mode

I've found that if you have the "**Always**" location permission on iOS for an app... even without initializing the `CLLocationManager`, it always shows the location arrow in the status bar unless the app is "force quit" using the task switcher.

I'm sure that this is on purpose for full disclosure, but it's not accurate considering the location isn't being used. Is there a mistake here that's causing the arrow to display (again, `CLLocationManager` is NOT initialized) or is this behavior normal these days in iOS 10 since the app **could** suddenly request location at any point?

Answer (score 0):

The permission states that the app can request the location in the background.

iOS gives this as full-disclosure to the user. They can then visit privacy settings for Location Services and see a colour-coded indicator for a more accurate depiction of when location updates were made.

Comment: So even without using the location it shows the arrow?